# Why isnt my slider showing up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm working on making a custom button that drops down a jquery ui slider beneath it. The idea is you can slide the slider and it changes the background color of the button. For some reason, the slider isn't appearing and I cant figure out why.

```
<div id="button-container">
    <div id="button">
        <div id="inner_triangle_button"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="slider_container">
       <div id="slider_container_triangle"></div>
       <div id="shadow_slider"></div>
   </div>
</div>

<script>
$('#button').click(function() { 

    if ( !$('#slider_container').is(":visible") )
        $('#slider_container').fadeIn(100);
    else
        $('#slider_container').fadeOut(100);
});

$(function() {
    $('.shadow_slider').slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 255,
        change: updateColor,
        slide: updateColor
    });
});

function updateColor() {
    var color = $('#shadow_slider').slider("value")
    $('#button').css('background', '#'+color+'0000');
}
</script>
```

I've made a JSFiddle for the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/drs4/bpsb20wd/5/

Comment: Is the jQuery UI stylesheet loaded?

Comment: Did you import jQuery UI?

Comment: You're selecting the element by class `$('.shadow_slider')` but the element has only the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadn't imported the jquery-ui.css file and the wrong selector was being used